# simple git repository organization

Tags: git

I a git newbie and having a bit of difficulty getting started.  Currently, I am the only developer on the project in question.

I have 2 personal machines  on which I do development (running dropbox) and a server where I deploy and debug (not running dropbox). I have ssh access to the server.  I do not have ssh access to the personal machines from the server.

My question: How to create/arrange my repositories.

My workflow begins on personal machine A, moves to personal machine B.  I iterate between these machines until I am happy. Then I want to push the result to the server.  I then do more mods on the server which need to be brought back to  the personal machines, ... Until everything settles down.

I feel like there should be a straightforward way to do this but I seem to be falling over myself ending up with unconnected repositories that are supposed to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is having a [central repository](http://toroid.org/ams/git-central-repo-howto), and do all of your pushes and pulls to that.   I would suggest creating one on the server with ssh access, since you should have access to it consistently, and with you as the only user, there will be very little additional traffic.

I do much the same thing, and don't even bother to use the --shared flag when creating the central repo.  With only one user, creating the bare repository and setting it up as the remote for all of your work areas should work fine.